# Cloud database instead local xamarine

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-development

I create app and all work fine
Need to replace string instead local database to be cloud database
Data in table database are same

New string is:

Data Source=94.251.1.1,1433;Initial Catalog="BCC";User ID=admin;Password=admin

String is fake ofcourse

MY sql is database

```
SQLiteConnection con;
        public SQLiteConnection GetConnectionWithCreateDatabase()
        {
            string fileName = "sampleDatabase.db3";
            string documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string path = Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);
            con = new SQLiteConnection(path);
            con.CreateTable<Employee>();
            return con;
        }
```